# Read a large amount of text contaning white spaces in matlab

Tags: matlab, file

I have a  '.txt'(ANSI encoding) file that contains an essay of about 880 words. 
I want to read the text with the white spaces.
I want to read that file in matlab but matlab throws **'Buffer overflow'** error.

i am using the following code:

```
e=textread(pathToFile,'whitespace','');
%%% further processing
```

I am using Matlab 2011. Can anyone suggest a workaround for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the input stream is too large to fit in your current buffer (by default, the maximum string length, in bytes is `4095`).

You can increase the buffer size using the `'bufsize'` optional parameter, like

```
e = textread(pathToFile, 'whitespace', '', 'bufsize', 8191); % or larger
```

Alternatively, to import large data files, consider to **read the file in segments**, which reduces the amount of memory required. Check out [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/import-large-text-files.html) for examples.

Check out [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textread.html) for more info.

Comment: All the link posted have shown data reading from a formatted text file whereas I have a to read from an non-formatted text file.

Answer (score 2):

You could use textscan:

```
C = textscan(fileID,'%s', 100, 'Delimiter', '\n');
```

This stores the first 100 lines (as delimited by the newline character) from the open fileID in a cell array.  White space is preserved.

Comment: but i don't know the number of lines ahead of time...is there any funtion to get the number of lines in the text file?

Comment: You don't need to specify the number - remove that and it will just read the individual lines in until it hits EOF.

Comment: @nkjt i tried it on matlab 2013 and it works perfectly. But on matlab 2011b it does not convert the text read from the file to string type